# How to translate this SQL query to a LINQ query

Tags: sql, entity-framework, linq, dbcontext

I am trying to get this SQL query into LINQ syntax but having a hard time. 
Can someone help me out?

```
SELECT * 
FROM
    (SELECT
         DESCR,  
         SUM(CONSUMPTIONCOST) AS CUSUMPTIONCOST, 
         SUM(SCHEDULEDREPAIRCOST) AS SCHEDULEDREPAIRCOST,
         SUM(PALS) AS PALSUM,
         SUM(UNSCHEDULEDREPAIRCOST) AS UNSCHEDULEDREPAIRCOST,
         SUM(O_S_Price) AS O_S_PRICE_SUM,
         SUM(PALS) AS PALS,
         SUM(CGAI_TOTAL) AS CGAI_TOTAL,
         SUM(SE_TOTAL) AS SE_TOTAL,
         SUM(MISCADDER_TOTAL) AS MISCADDER_TOTAL,
         SUM(CODB_TOTAL) AS CODB_TOTAL,
         SUM(OS_PRICE_PLUSFACTORS) AS OS_PRICE_PLUSFACTORS,
         SUM(PALS + O_S_PRICE) AS COST,
         RANK() OVER(ORDER BY SUM(PALS + O_S_PRICE) DESC) AS COST_RANK
     FROM
         jamResult.Parts_Ace 
     GROUP BY 
         DESCR, RUN_NAME) AS X
WHERE 
    COST_RANK > 0 
    AND COST_RANK < 10 
ORDER BY 
    COST_RANK ASC
```

Comment: Can you be more specific about what part of this you need help with and what you've tried so far?

Comment: I guess the problem is with `RANK()` which has no good LINQ equivalent (I'm not sure it has working LINQ to Entities equivalent at all)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please never just post SQL and ask for conversion. At least show a class model so navigation properties and the multiplicity of associations are visible. Also,show your own first efforts. They clarify more to us than you might think.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for `COST_RANK` values between 0 and 10 (the first 9 results ranked descending by cost--those with ranks of 1 through 9), you can do `OrderByDescending` in LINQ, followed by a `Take(9)` to narrow the result set:

```
var result = yourQuery.OrderByDescending(x => x.Cost).Take(9);
```